# Delete all users from firebase auth console

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Is there an easy way to delete all registered users from firebase console?
For example, I created a hundred users from my development environment, and now I want to delete all of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*firebaser here*

## Update 2016-11-08 *original answer below*

We just released the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which supports administrative use-cases, such as [deleting a user account without requiring that user to sign in first](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

**original answer**

There is currently no API in Firebase Authentication to delete a user without requiring that user to sign in. We know this limits the usability of our API and are working to add such functionality in a future release. But as usual, we don't provide specific timelines for when the feature will be available.

For the moment your only work arounds are to:

- sign in as each test user in the app and delete the user from there
- delete each user in turn from the Firebase Console

Comment: Can you please consider removing the 'Are you sure prompt' in the Firebase Console if you 'Shift' + click 'Delete account'. This would mimic the behaviour in the database and would significantly speed things up.

Comment: Can I "sign in as each test user" from appengine , without browser? Can I delete users from app engine directly somehow or via some web services?

Comment: in the NodeJs firebase-admin SDK is there no way to get all users then for each user `admin.auth().deleteUser(uid);`

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen I see there is not python admin SDK. Is there some way to use the nodeJS admin SDK inside python.

Comment: Am glad to know this is now possible via firebase admin sdk. Would be cool to know if these can also be uploaded and used as google https functions? TIA!

Answer (score 114):

As in updated answer, you can probably use firebase admin tools now, but if you don't want – here is a bit more solid javascript to remove users in the web:

```
var intervalId;

var clearFunction = function() {
  var size = $('[aria-label="Delete account"]').size()
  if (size == 0) {
    console.log("interval cleared")
    clearInterval(intervalId)
    return
  }
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * size)
  $('[aria-label="Delete account"]')[index].click();
  setTimeout(function () {
     $(".md-raised:contains(Delete)").click()
  }, 1000);
};

intervalId = setInterval(clearFunction, 300)
```

Just run it in developer tools

Comment: This works, however make sure to have the tab open not switch to a different one while it's running

Comment: How do you run this in developer tools? I pasted it into the console. Something else to do then?

Answer (score 82):

#### For the new Firebase update

Try this code for the latest Firebase update. Open the console, paste this code and hit enter.

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click()
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-focus-indicator mat-mdc-menu-item ng-star-inserted')).at(-1).click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button  mat-mdc-raised-button mat-mdc-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! Just note: if there's an anonymous account in the list, change index in second 'getElementsByClassName' from 2 to 1. Also you can set shorter interval, i used 500.

Comment: You are the best :). This works in 21.04.2021

Comment: how does this work>? where exactly do i write this code

Comment: @b.john 
- Go to the auth page in your firebase console
- Open the dev console in your browser 
- Paste this code and hit enter

Comment: I made it working by changing 2nd command's index to 1, not 2 
 =>  document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[1].click()

Comment: This works for me 17.09.2021. For users authenticate by mail id's just use [2] in second line and others who use mobile authentication use [1] in second line.

Comment: Still works as of Jan 7 2021. Thank you so much!

Comment: @GregSadetsky 2022* 

Comment: haha, you're right, 2022*!! I'll keep my original comment for posterity. :-) Cheers and best wishes

Comment: That's some beautiful hackery. Still working 21 feb 2022.

Comment: Thanks. Crazy that this is still needed in 2022.

Comment: Just gave it another shot and it's still working, 15 Feb 2023 

Comment: Still works in 22 Mar 2023. I had to update the delay to 5000ms

Comment: I updated this to work on 23  Feb 2024

Answer (score 45):

Because I'm pretty lazy at clicking buttons and elements in the UI, I set up a small client script:

```
$('[aria-label="Delete account"]').click()
setTimeout(function () {
   $(".md-raised:contains(Delete)").click()
}, 1000);
```

You may need to run it multiple times, but it is much better than wasting the time clicking things on the screen manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot...works great..saves me 2 clicks and moving the mouse around :)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful :)

Comment: @LuisMejíaF. I expected it to be useful when posting the answer :) Always, automate the stuff when there's something repetitive to do :-)

Comment: yo, very useful bro)

Comment: Thanks, bro. Very helpful. :)

Comment: how do i run this script?

Comment: @mjpablo23 Open the browser developer tools (Right click on the page and `Inspect` or `Inspect Element`), then go to the `Console` tab and paste the code and press the *return* / *enter* key.

Comment: what do I right click on?  I'm on the Firebase->Authentication page in the Firebase console.

Comment: @mjpablo23 Simply right click anywhere on the page.

Comment: Got a TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '$('[aria-label="Delete account"]').click') - suggestions?

Comment: @Praxiteles Can you please ask a question and eventually post the link here? I would need to see the code for context.

Answer (score 32):

## Fully working solution using Firebase Admin SDK

Using the Firebase Admin SDK is **really easy** and the **recommended** way to perform such tasks on your Firebase data. This solution is **unlike** the other makeshift solutions using the developer console.

I just put together a Node.js script to delete all users in your Firebase authentication. I have already tested it by deleting ~10000 users. I simply ran the following Node.js code.

#### To setup Firebase Admin SDK

Create a new folder. Run the following in terminal

```
npm init
sudo npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Now create an `index.js` file in this folder.

#### Steps to follow:

- Go to your Firebase project -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts.
- Click on `Generate new Private Key` to download the JSON file. Copy the path to JSON file and replace it in the code below in the path to service accounts private key json file.
- Also, copy the `databaseURL` from the settings page. Replace it in the code.
- Copy and paste the code in `index.js`.
- Run in terminal `node index.js`. Watch the mayhem!

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require("/path/to/service/accounts/private/key/json/file");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "/url/to/your/database"
});

function deleteUser(uid) {
    admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
        .then(function() {
            console.log('Successfully deleted user', uid);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
        });
}

function getAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
    admin.auth().listUsers(100, nextPageToken)
        .then(function(listUsersResult) {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
                uid = userRecord.toJSON().uid;
                deleteUser(uid);
            });
            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
                getAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error listing users:', error);
        });
}

getAllUsers();
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm blocked right now tho, api didn't let me delete more about 8,000 users in

Comment: Glad it worked. However, I did not face any blocking or restrictions when I tried it.

Comment: just dont let the general public have access to this

Comment: Nice. Here it complained about reaching the limit after ~100 removals, but just executed it again to finishing removing all. I recommend using .gitignore on the cred.json file.

Comment: @Jorsh if you want ot avoid restrictions in my case simple timeout helped when calling getAllUsers again:

            setTimeout(() => {
                getAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
            }, 6000);

Comment: Here's it as a gist you can save:
https://gist.github.com/joshpetit/b6cf918a9beac1f4e86270475a61cb11

Comment: This is definitely the way you're supposed to do it, great answer!

Answer (score 27):

```
setInterval(() => {
  $('[aria-label="Delete account"]').first().click()
  setTimeout(()=>{
    $(".md-raised:contains(Delete)").click()
  }, 100)
}, 2000);
```

designed to avoid calling `delete` endpoint very often, since google fails with `404` error.

Comment: haha, thanks @AndroidRuntimeException , now someone should release an international version (seeing all those different languages above) and a version with official API, and this post will become ideal, lol

Comment: This was awesome to watch in action! Thank you to you.

Comment: @gbhall ahahaha, glad you had fun with it.

Comment: I had slow internet sow I had to put interval of 5000

Comment: That's cool @Murtuza ideally it would be linked to the event handler when XHR requests are finished.

Comment: I love this solution!  I'm adding an if statement to count for the need to go to the next page though.

Comment: hey @Chris, great to hear! Feel free to share your solution. Let's make firebase easier for us all :)

Comment: @www.eugenehp.tk posted :)

Answer (score 7):

Slightly increased your helper script.

German firebase site version:

```
$('[aria-label="Nutzermenü öffnen"]').click();
$('[aria-label="Konto löschen"]').click();
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.md-raised:contains(Löschen)').click();
  }, i * 200);
}
```

For the english version just replace the text.
This way you can delete 20 or more users once executed.

Comment: Is this right so far?

"Löschen" = "Delete" 
"Konto löschen" = "Delete account"
"Nutzermenü öffnen" = ?

Comment: 200 ms was short in my case. Set to 1000 - 1500 ms and it works!

Comment: @Aldasa "Open user menu" is Nutzermenü öffnen

Answer (score 5):

Used this code successfully on 11/16/2020:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('[aria-label="View more options"]')[0].click()
    document.querySelectorAll('.mat-menu-item')[2].click()
    document.querySelector('.confirm-button').click()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If you want to get possible rep for your answer then provide substantial more info to boos quality of your answer. 15 answer were before you...

Answer (score 5):

## Tested at 10 Oct 2021

This will click on the last button in the context menu which is always the Delete button, so it works on all account types

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted');
    buttons.item(buttons.length - 1).click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

#### This code still works as by June 20, 2023.

Following are the steps to delete all users in one go.

1. Open **Firebase Authentication**
2. Right Click and choose **Inspect**
3. In the developer tools, tap the **Console** tab
4. Paste this code there

```
setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
      let deleteButtonPosition = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted').length - 1
      document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[deleteButtonPosition].click()
      document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

5. Hit **Enter**

If above **query** is not working, try this one:

```
setInterval(() => {
    // click on 3 dots next to user
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-icon-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
    // click on delete account
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-item mat-mdc-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted')[2].click();
    // click on delete in confirmation dialog
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-warn mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
// changed timer to 2000 as it was not deleting after 500ms
}, 2000);
```

This will start deleting your users.

Answer (score 4):

```
setInterval(() => {
  if ($('[aria-label="Delete account"]').length > 0) {
    $('[aria-label="Delete account"]').first().click()
    setTimeout(()=>{
      $(".md-raised:contains(Delete)").click()
    }, 100)
  } else {
    $('[aria-label="Reload"]').first().click()
  }
}, 2000);
```

Try this one.  It's an update to @www.eugenehp.tk answer above that takes into account the need to refresh the page if you have more than one page of entries.

Comment: Brilliant solution, works like a charm! Thank you! 

Answer (score 4):

**Updated 03/2022 working (with load next records page)**

```
setInterval(() => {
        var RecordsCount = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base').length;
        if (RecordsCount>0)
        {
            document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
            let deleteButtonPosition = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted').length - 1
            document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[deleteButtonPosition].click()
            document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
        }
        else
        {
              //reload more records
              $('[aria-label="Reload"]').first().click();
        }
}, 800);
```

Comment: You helped me delete 50k accounts. Thank you! The only problem with the script was that I had to increase the delay for the last 2k accounts to 1 second (1000 ms).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I used this script to delete all users at once in Firebase console:

```
$('[aria-label="Delete account"]').each(function() {
  $(this).click();
  $('[ng-click="controller.submit()"]').click()
})
```

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/authentication/users

Comment: How to delete only single user by uid?

Comment: Received an error:
 VM225:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'each')
    at <anonymous>:1:35 - Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Just created a script to run into console when the Firebase Authentication window is opened.
**Step 1**: Go to the Authentication Tab of your Firebase Project

**Step 2**: Press `Ctrl + Shift + i` to go to browser console

**Step 3**: Copy the following code and paste it into the console.

```js
(function delScript() {
  const allRowNodes = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  if (!allRowNodes || !allRowNodes.length) {
    console.log("No Accounts to delete ");
    return null;
  }
  allRowNodes.forEach((curRowNode, idx) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      curRowNode.querySelector(".edit-account-button").click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("button.mat-menu-item:nth-child(3)").click();
        setTimeout(() => {
          document
            .querySelector("fire-dialog-actions button:nth-child(2)")
            .click();
          setTimeout(() => {
            const backdrop = document.querySelector(
              ".cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"
            );
            backdrop.click();
          }, 1200);
        }, idx * 1600);
      }, idx * 800);
    }, idx * 800);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @[Fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23074152/fernando-asmat) for your answer. Needed to change button number from 1 to 2, increased the time from 500 to 2000 and it worked like a charm.

```
setInterval(() => {
    // click on 3 dots next to user
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-icon-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
    // click on delete account
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-item mat-mdc-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted')[2].click();
    // click on delete in confirmation dialog
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-warn mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
// changed timer to 2000 as it was not deleting after 500ms
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Russian version

```js
var intervalId;

var clearFunction = function() {
if ($('[aria-label="Удаление аккаунта"]').size() == 0) {
console.log("interval cleared")
clearInterval(intervalId)
return
}
$('[aria-label="Удаление аккаунта"]')[0].click();
setTimeout(function () {
$('[ng-click="controller.submit()"]').click()
}, 1000);
};

intervalId = setInterval(clearFunction, 3000)
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to create a separate file and import my firebase-admin and simply run the following:

```
const admin = require('./firebase_admin');

const listAllUsers = () => {
  console.log('list all users');
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000)
    .then((listUsersResult) => {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
        const user = userRecord.toJSON();
        admin
          .auth()
          .deleteUser(user.uid)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('successfully deleted user');
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error('error deleting user: ', err);
          });
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
};
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

The concept here is that we want to retrieve all the users from our user auth table, then cycle throw and delete them one at a time using the deleteUser admin auth method.

In the terminal, I simply used node to call the function in the file (so let's say the filename is `delete_users.js`, I just called `node delete_users.js` and the listUsers function was invoked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but a few things I had to go add on. Required the addition of firebase-functions and also a private key to give the script credentials to run. Followed these steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 1):

French version,

```
var intervalId;

var clearFunction = function() {
  if ($('[aria-label="Supprimer le compte"]').size() == 0) {
    console.log("interval cleared")
    clearInterval(intervalId)
    return
  }
  $('[aria-label="Supprimer le compte"]')[0].click();
  setTimeout(function () {
     $(".md-raised:contains(Supprimer)").click()
  }, 1000);
};

intervalId = setInterval(clearFunction, 3000)
```

PS: if you are not web developer and "Execute in tools developer" means nothing to you, here the procedure.

- Open your firebase authentication/users page with Chrome
- Press control + shif+ J
- In the console tab, paste this code and press enter.
- If the language matched with the code your paste, account will start to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

if u have anonymous accounts

```js
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted').length === 3 ? 2 : 1].click()
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the below script on the console and it will delete all users at once.

```
$('.edit-account-button').click();

$('.mat-menu-content button:last-child').click()

$('.fire-dialog-actions .confirm-button').click()
```

Comment: THANK YOU, out of all the answers, this one worked perfectly, appreciate it!!!! <3

Answer (score 1):

## Updated 2021 working answer

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  if ($('.edit-account-button').length === 0) {
    clearInterval(interval)
  } else {
    $('.edit-account-button').first().click()
    $('button:contains("Delete account")').click()
    $('.confirm-button').click()
  }
}, 1000)
```

https://gist.github.com/cupcakearmy/8c314b891e6958f26374c0205bac85e9

Answer (score 1):

**This Works now 17.09.2021**

Go to your firebase console, click inspect element and select console and paste this code there.

```
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[2].click()
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

For authentication types:
if you authenticate by mail id use [2] in the second line,
if you use mobile authentication use[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCHCd.png) in the second line

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I will just add that if you have many users you need to press the reload button so just make another setInterval:

```
const reloadButton = document.querySelectorAll("button")[10];
const arr = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base');
```

and the setInterval:

```
setInterval(() => {
if(!arr.length) reloadButton.click()
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')).at(-1).click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

This code works if the user's options also include MFA

Test Date: 15/10/2023

Simple open developers option -> console -> paste and hit enter

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to some.
If you have access to the firebase user console - just save the page as an html and use the following to delete users with node. need to setup firebase-admin

```
let fs = require('fs'),
  admin = require('firebase-admin'),
  cheerio = require('cheerio');

// initialize firebase admin here
admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json'),
databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});

// use cheerio to load the html file you downloaded
$ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync('./yourfirebaseconsole.html'));
$('.a12n-user-uid .fb-table-cell-wrapper').each(function() {
  admin.auth().deleteUser($(this).text());
}).then(() => {
  console.log('successfully delete user');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('error occurred ', error);
});
```

I would recommend doing a dry run of the html parsing logic once on the page using browser by just running this and confirming that only user ids are displayed in the result. In my case this returned all UIDs

```
$('.a12n-user-uid .fb-table-cell-wrapper').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used it

```js
var openMenuItemForFirstUser = function () {
    const menuItem = $('[ng-click="controller.deleteUser()"]')
    if (menuItem.size()) {
        menuItem[0].classList.add("deletingThisUser")
        menuItem[0].click();
        setTimeout(deleteUser, 10, 0)
    } else {
        console.log("No users found...")
    }
};

var deleteUser = function (t) {
    const confirmButton = $('[ng-click="controller.submit()"]')
    if (confirmButton.size()) {
        console.log("deleting user")
        confirmButton[0].click()
        setTimeout(waitForDeletion, 10, 0)
    } else {
        if (t > 500) console.log("fail trying delete user")
        else setTimeout(deleteUser, 10, parseInt(t) + 1)
    }
}

var waitForDeletion = function (t) {
    const deletingThisUser = $('.deletingThisUser')
    if (deletingThisUser.size()) {
        if (t > 500) console.log("fail wait for deletion")
        else setTimeout(waitForDeletion, 10, parseInt(t) + 1)
    } else {
        setTimeout(openMenuItemForFirstUser, 10)
    }
}

setTimeout(openMenuItemForFirstUser, 1000)
console.log("Deleting all users... Press F5 to cancel it")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the previous, none worked, so I created one for my needs:

```
setInterval(() => {

  if ($('[aria-label="View more options"]').length > 0) {

    $('[aria-label="View more options"]')[0].click()

    if ($('[role="menuitem"]').length > 0) {

      $('[role="menuitem"]')[1].click()

      if ($('[class="confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn"]').length > 0) {

        $('[class="confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn"]').click()
      }
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another script that can be used as a bookmarklet. Simply

1. create a new bookmark (Ctrl-D)
2. select "more"'
3. paste the script into the URL input

You can then just click the bookmark to delete all users. The script will stop when there's no more users or you navigate away. If you're not using the english version, update the `*Text` variables with the corresponding text.

```
javascript: (function () {
  const deleteText = 'Delete account';
  const deleteConfirmationText = 'Delete';

  const editSelector = '.edit-account-button';
  const deleteSelector = `button:contains(${deleteText})`;
  const deleteConfirmationSelector = `button span:contains(${deleteConfirmationText})`;
  const waitForAnimation = 350;

  const deleteUsers = () => {
    const editAccountButton = $(editSelector).first();

    if (!editAccountButton.size()) {
      console.log('Delete complete.');
      return;
    }

    editAccountButton.first().click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(deleteSelector).first().click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        $(deleteConfirmationSelector).first().click();
        setTimeout(() => {
          deleteUsers();
        }, waitForAnimation * 1.5);
      }, waitForAnimation);
    }, waitForAnimation);
  };

  deleteUsers();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I had firebaseAdmin hooked up to an emulator for testing. To clear the database before each test I combined the `listUsers` function with the `deleteUser` function. *Caution* you probably don't want to create this type of functionality for a real database.

My code looked like this.

```
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird"

function clearAllUsers() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => admin.auth().listUsers())
    .then((response) => response.users)
    .then((users) =>
      Bluebird.map(users, (user: { uid: string }) =>
        admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid),
      ),
    );
}
```

But you could also use async await and accomplish the same thing with

```
import * as Bluebird from "bluebird"
async function clearAllUsers() {
  const usersResponse = await admin.auth().listUsers();
  const users = usersResponse.users;
  return await Bluebird.map(users, (user: { uid: string }) =>
    admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid),
  );
}
```

Also if you do happen to use an emulator for testing, the UI for it comes shipped with a delete all button. see (here)[https://imgur.com/3Xil86I]

Answer (score 0):

### Simple delete all users - ESM

```js
// delete.ts or delete.mjs

import admin from 'firebase-admin';
import cred from './credentials.json';
let firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(cred as admin.ServiceAccount)
});
const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken?: string) => {
    // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
    admin
        .auth()
        .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
        .then(async (listUsersResult) => {
            await admin.auth().deleteUsers(listUsersResult.users.map((u) => u.uid));
            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
                // List next batch of users.
                listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error listing users:', error);
        });
};
listAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on 2022/02/19

```
setInterval(() => {
    $('[mattooltip="View more options"]').first().click()
    setTimeout(()=>{
        $(".mat-focus-indicator:contains(Delete)").click()
        setTimeout(()=>{
           $(".mat-warn").click()
        }, 100)
    }, 100)
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to improve [yaman-katby answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64825547/8365583), because I didn't want to press ***"refresh button"*** every time the list was empty.

---

***An updated for my answer:***

So, if you open multiple windows (no fullscreen mode), and order by different ways, you can delete all your users. But sometimes you will find an error that you erased a user previously.

That why I added `times` and `elementSize` variables, to refresh the list and continue deleting the users

```js
let times=0;
let elementSize=0;
setInterval(() => {
    if( (document.getElementsByClassName('no-user-text ng-star-inserted').length > 0) || ( elementSize == document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base').length && times == 3 ) || times == 50 ) {
        times=0;
        elementSize=0;
        document.querySelectorAll('.mat-focus-indicator.mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger.mat-icon-button.mat-button-base[data-test-id="reload-user-button"]')[0].click()
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click();
    let deleteButtonPosition = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted').length - 1;
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted')[deleteButtonPosition].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click();
        elementSize = document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base').length;
        times++;
    }
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated 12/2023 working**

```js
setInterval(() => {
    var RecordsCount = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mat-icon-button mat-button-base').length;
    console.log("RecordsCount: " + RecordsCount);
    if (RecordsCount > 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click();
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-item-text');
        for (var index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
            if (x[index].textContent ==" Delete account ") {
                x[index].click();
            }
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-warn mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
    } else {
        console.log("Reload------");
        document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click();
    }
}, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this at 2023/12, on dev console:

```
setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-icon-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-item mat-mdc-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted')[1].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-warn mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
}, 500);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**the following worked for me on December 21, 2023:**

```
var i = 14; 
setInterval(() => {
    let num = i.toString();
    let name = 'mat-mdc-menu-item mat-mdc-focus-indicator ng-tns-c1638460095-' + num + ' ng-star-inserted';
    document.getElementsByClassName('mat-mdc-menu-trigger mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger edit-account-button mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-icon-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click()
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(name)).at(-1).click()
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mat-mdc-raised-button mat-warn mat-mdc-button-base')[0].click();
    i = i + 1;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**2024**

```
function clickConfirmButton() {
    var confirmButton = document.querySelector('button.confirm-button.mdc-button.mdc-button--raised.mat-mdc-raised-button.mat-warn.mat-mdc-button-base');
    if (confirmButton) {
        confirmButton.click();
    } else {
        console.error('Confirm button not found!');
    }
}

setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector('button[data-test-id="edit-account-button"]').click();
    document.querySelector('button.mat-mdc-menu-item:last-of-type').click();

    setTimeout(clickConfirmButton, 500);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

firebase has updated you can use this code now old code will not work

```
 setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-account-button mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-trigger mat-icon-button mat-button-base')[0].click()
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-focus-indicator mat-menu-item  ng-star-inserted')
    for (let index = 0; index  < x.length; index++) {
        if(x[index].textContent =="Delete account"){ x[index].click() }
        }
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirm-button mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn')[0].click()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).