# Get Firebase users authenticated through Facebook or Google

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use Firebase Admin SDK to delete authenticated users. All the users can be deleted using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808712/delete-all-users-from-firebase-auth-console/56365233#56365233). However, I only want to delete those authenticated with a specific auth service provider, i.e., delete users authenticated with Google/Facebook and leave the ones who signed in using email.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {

        //Check if the user signed in with Google/Facebook

        if (userRecord.providerId == "Google" || userRecord.providerId == "Facebook") {
         //Delete user
          admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid)
        }

      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error);
    });
}
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

This is untested, so I'm not sure if this exact code will work, but you get the idea.