# If I chose to launch my app with my current test DB?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am debating whether or not I should launch my app using my test project on firebase. Its works fine the only thing is that there are 400 users in the athentication which I cant remove.

Question:

**If I chose to launch my app with my current DB (which has like 400 test users) would I come across any sort of problem (of course I would delete any existing data in DB and storage)? And 2 is it easy to switch to a new project shortly after?**

What I am currently testing:

```
    const deleteAllUsers = async (nextPageToken?) => {
    // List batch of users, 10 at a time.
    const listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers(10, nextPageToken);
    listUsersResult.users.forEach(async userRecord => {
      await admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid);
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
    });
    if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
      // Wait to delete each set of users to abide by Firebase timeout
      setTimeout(() => deleteAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken), 2000);
    } else {
      console.log('no more users found');
    }
};
await deleteAllUsers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You can delete current test users one by one from console or as a whole using the terminal or admin sdk

2- It's easy to switch projects later on, but it's hard to transfer data (possible, but not a one click)

To edit user from terminal of your computer:

1- [Install Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli)

```
> npm install -g firebase-tools
> firebase login
> firebase init
```

2- [export user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) with filename extension to choose format .json or .csv

```
> firebase auth:export account_file_name.json
```

or

```
> firebase auth:export account_file_name.csv
```

3- edit the file (keep a copy just in case) then import it to Firebase

```
> firebase auth:import account_file_name.json
```

**Note:** I've only tried exporting the user accounts, I've never imported it back, so I don't know what you're facing. I suggest you look into keeping a back up if there are important things and only do it if you're confident.
You can also create a new dummy project and play with it!

Comment: "Using the terminal" do you mean on firebase or one local computer: could u give me some guidance on how to do that?

Comment: Using firebase's web console you can delete users from auth manually, it is also possible from the admin sdk

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with your current system and only want to remove users, this is easy to do either through the [firebase admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), or web console.

*Using the SDK*

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
  });
```

Full details available at the following link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user

This is also discussed in [Delete all users from firebase auth console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808712/delete-all-users-from-firebase-auth-console)

*Using the web console*
[image: delete firebase user from console]